# как создать QPixmap с размерами 30000x30000?

Tags: c++, qt

При создание QPixmap(30000, 30000), выдает такую ошибку 
libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data

что не так ?

возможно ли сделать так, создать QPixmap(30000, 10000) (так работает) и записать в файл, а при следующей итерации дописать в файл другой QPixmap(30000, 10000) ?

Comment: Может, памяти ему не хватает?

Comment: Может есть какие то ограничения на размер изображения?

Comment: @Qwertiy: ... и он не бросает исключение?

Comment: Хотя _какая-то_ ошибка должна быть — вы заказываете картинку размером в 3 с половиной гигабайта :-)

Comment: только выдает ошибку " libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR libpng error: Invalid IHDR data"

Comment: а возможно сделать так, записать в файл с флагом QIODevice::Append по частям изображение ?

Comment: Определенно можно сказать что упомянутый IHDR по стандарту не накладывает таких ограничений на размеры изображения, допустимо до 2^31 пикселей по каждой стороне.

Comment: @VladD, Qt не бросает исключений.

Comment: @ixSci: Ох. А как же там принято сообщать об ошибках?

Comment: @VladD, ну «коды возврата» только и остаются :) Или вот так, как выше в вопросе: что-то написать в консоль

Comment: @ixSci: Ну, есть ещё ужасный вариант, принятый у `istream`: `operator bool`. `int x; cin >> x; if (!cin) ... `.

Comment: @VladD, я просто предположил. Где-то уже встречал подобную проблему... А с Qt никогда не работал.

Comment: @LopatinVitaly, вариант с нехваткой памяти самый вероятный. Сколько ОЗУ на ПК вместе со свапом?

Comment: 6 оперативки 12 свап

Comment: @АнтонСазонов: тут скорее не нехватка оперативки, а адресного пространства. Небось программа под 32 бита?

Comment: нет, 64 бита ...

Comment: @LopatinVitaly: Под 64 бита операционка или программа?

Comment: @LopatinVitaly, а можно поподробней о создании QPixmap? Как это происходит? Лично я не до конца понимаю при чём тут вообще PNG. Приведи простой пример в виде кода.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов,  все просто, создаю QPixmap(30000, 30000). в нем рисуем через QPainter... а потом сохраняем как файл png

Comment: А версия libpng какая? И как она инициалтзируется? Понятно, что это недра qt, но всё же. Интересное чтиво: http://libpng.sourceforge.net/decompression_bombs.html ну и при выборе другого формата такая же картина? Ну вопрос больше для багтрекера проекта qt.

Comment: @LopatinVitaly, я так понимаю, ошибка появляется не при создании QPixmap? Почему бы тебе не подредактировать своё сообщение, добавив в него небольшую последовательность кода, при которой появляется ошибка с описанием места её появления!?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант написать обертку которая динамически подгружает с диска ваш QPixMap, то есть разбить исходное изображение на более мелкие, в оперативной памяти хранить только один кусок, при обращении к конкретному куску загружать его в ОЗУ, просто перезаписывая в выделенную память( куски бдут одного размера ведь ), естетсвенно все эти кусочки будут храниться отдельно. А еще может быть есть такие СУБД которые позволят хранить BLOB-поля кусочками

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю скомпилировать программу под x64.
Это должно решить проблему с лимитом на память.

---

Просто дописывать в файл скорее всего не получится, поскольку графические форматы предполагают наличие какого-то начала файла, которое окажется у тебя ещё и между частями. Однако, если QPixmap сам предоставляет возможность дозаписать файл, то это может подойти.

Comment: не работает ....